# Twig: Allow HTML, but escape script

Tags: symfony, twig, html-sanitizing

I am investigating a possible `XSS` attack vector for my application.

What I have:

- FormType with a single `textarea` field. Normally this field can contain `html` tags.
- `Twig` template that renders the data inserted.

I use that form to insert the following content:

```
<b>Some valid HTML text</b>
<script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS")</script>
```

Viewing that data would require escaping. I am familiar with few strategies when it comes to escaping the data.

1) `raw` filter: Completely disables escaping -> introduces possible XSS

2) `e` filter:

- `html` flavor outputs: `<b>Some valid HTML text</b> <script type="text/javascript">alert("XSS")</script>`
- `js` flavor outputs: `\x3Cb\x3ESome\x20valid\x20HTML\x20text\x3C\x2Fb\x3E\x0D\x0A\x3Cscript\x20type\x3D\x22text\x2Fjavascript\x22\x3Ealert\x28\x22XSS\x22\x29\x3C\x2Fscript\x3E`

3) `{{ var|striptags('<br>')|raw }}`, outputs: **Some valid HTML text** alert("XSS")

This one works, but somehow I don't like it. I am rather looking for a black-list solution, not white-list.

**Now the question:**

Is there any other escaping strategy that allows `html` tags but escapes `<script>` tag like `e("js")` filter does?

Should I "kill" the script during the form submission or during the `Twig` rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest adding a new Twig filter that fits your needs.

It should look something like

```
{{var | filter_black_listed() }}
```

and in the filter logic you add something like

```php
class FilterBlackListedExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $blacklistedTags = ['script', 'p'];

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('filter_black_listed', array($this, 'htmlFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function htmlFilter($html)
    {
        foreach ($this->blacklistedTags as $tag) {
            preg_replace('/(<' . $tag . '>)(.*)(<\/' . $tag . '>)/g', '', $html);
        }

        return $html; // maybe even apply the raw filter also afterwards.
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'filter_black_listed_extension';
    }
}
```

let me know if you don't manage to make this work :)

Comment: Yes, I've considered writing my own solution :) But, the question is, is this safe enough?

Comment: I did a bit of googling and this seems "safe enough" :) Thanks :)

Comment: Hey pcm! Just wanted to tell you that I only implemented my own filter about a week ago. Works beautifully. Thanks again! :)

Comment: +1 mate, you can use more secure and with more options link (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/extras/htmlfilter.php) in your htmlFilter()

Comment: I dont think this protects against `on-click` and similar attributes, but not sure if this is a huge concern...

Comment: This filter is not secure at all. It does not protect against script tags with attributes, onEvent attributes or javascript links.