# Symfony 2.7, Twig, and CKEditor -- How to safely allow some HTML output?

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, ckeditor, twig

So I'm making a blog with Symfony where people can leave comments when they register. I want people to be able to leave rich comments with more or less the HTML that you can insert using the Standard Package of CKEditor (images, font styles, blockquotes, tables) and also YouTube videos. I've been using the raw filter on Twig in order to allow all the HTML CKEditor generates to show on the comments. Unfortunately, this allows in all HTML ... so it makes for a very insecure website when everyone can come in and post whatever they want.

Is there a way for me to both keep CKEditor and also filter out insecure HTML/Javascript? In the past I would have simply implemented BB Code, which would give me full control of what gets converted to HTML but CKEditor directly generates HTML...

What is the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: I had a similar question not long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828075/twig-allow-html-but-escape-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So effectively you'd like white-list some HTML tags and attributes? If so, the easiest way to do this is with something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which allows you to set up rules for what HTML is allowed.

If you decide to use it, the setup can be a little involved if you read through the [documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs) but something like:

```
$config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);
$config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', [ '_blank' ]);
$config->set('Attr.AllowedRel', [ 'nofollow' ]);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,div,hr,img[src|alt],ul,ol,li,br,strong,b,em,i,span,a[href|target|rel],table,thead,tbody,tr,th,td,*[class|style]');

$purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
return $purifier->purify($userEnteredHtml);
```

Is what I've used in a number of projects, all of which have been pen-tested and come back clean for things like XSS and the like.

Comment: Very interesting. I can see something like this being integrated into my custom "wysiwyg" form type :)

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!