# Escaping tinyMCE javascript output in Symfony/Twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, escaping, tinymce, twig

I am using TinyMCE in Symfony. Everything works fine, I save user input in the database, but I want to make users's javascript not run on frontend when displaying their message. I tried

```
  {{ message.content|raw }}
```

But the problem is that it runs the javascript code.

Then I tried

```
{% autoescape 'js' %}
{{ message.content }}
{% endautoescape   %}
```

But it prints javascript as strange characters like `\x3C\x2Fp\x3E`.

How can I print javascript code as plaintext? Or how is it done to display the text properly formatted and not run the javascript part?

For instance,

```
<b>test</b> <script>alert()</script>
```

To be displayed similar to

**test** alert()

Comment: I had a similar question, although, I decided to remove <script> altogether. See my question here and answer by @pcm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828075/twig-allow-html-but-escape-script

Comment: Strange that nobody thought of this before. XSS attacks are the easiest to do. Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strip_tags` function:

```
{{ message.content | striptags('<p><b><br>') | raw }}
```

Tags inside `strip_tags` is allowed tags.

Comment: Isn't there a way to revert that? I want to allow anything except <script> and it's bothersome to write ALL the other tinyMCE-supported HTML tags inside there.

Comment: In this case you can use `replace`:   `{{  message.content | replace({"<script>" : "", "</script>" : ""}) | raw }}` but allowing users to input html markup is not secure, consider to use markdown, or if not suit you then use something like html purifier.

Comment: Why is it not secure? How can I make them use tinyMCE, then?

Comment: Because user can sent any malicious code if you allow any html tags, can change layout of page adding div's, styles etc. You can use html purifier bundle in twig as well, or before you save user input to database, or even make additional field in db where you save purified safe output to display. https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle